# Extract column metadata from rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis

I'm trying to read a csv file where metadata is placed on row 4 to 7

```
Source,"EUROSTAT","INE","BDP"
Magnitude,,,
Unit ,"Percent","Percent","Unit"
Series,"Rate","PIB","Growth"
```

Where the relevant data starts on row 10. This CSV format will always be fixed, with this sort of data and this row disposition

```
Date,Series1,Series2,Series3
30-09-2014,13.1,1.1,5.55
30-06-2014,13.9,0.9,5.63
31-03-2014,15.1,1.0,5.57
31-12-2013,15.3,1.6,5.55
30-09-2013,15.5,-1.0,5.66
30-06-2013,16.4,-2.1,5.65
```

What I've done was skip the first rows and read the data from Row 10 afterwards, and define the column metadata myself. However, the rows don't have the Unit type nor the magnitude that was defined in the Metadata header. In SSIS I do an Unpivot of the columns to an Indicator column so I have the `Date, Series, Value` style of table.

My question here is how can I make a table of the format `Date, Series, Value, Magnitude, Unit` where the `Series, Magnitude, Unit` are read from the first 10 rows?

Comment: So the desired output for the first row of actual data would be `30-09-2014,13.1,1.1,5.55,Rate,,Percent` with those last 3 columns repeating for all rows?

Comment: I'll add this information to the Question since it wasn't clear. The data comes formated as `DATE,Series1,Series2,Series3` where the `Series` metadata is from the row 7. What I wanted to pass into a table format would be the 'Unit' and 'Magnitude' as well, so I could have `DATE, Series1, Series2, Series3, Magnitude1, Magnitude2, Magnitude3, Unit1,Unit2,Unit3` and then unpivot to a table with just `DATE, Series, Magnitude, Unit`